# Over $5$ consecutive weekdays, what is the probability that he misses the bus on Tuesday and on two other days?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Probability that a student misses the bus is $0.2$ (and is independent of whether or not he missed the bus previously). Over $5$ consecutive weekdays, what is the probability that he misses the bus on Tuesday *and* on two other days?

The answer I got was $0.03072$
Working:

$$0.2 \cdot \left[\binom{4}{2} \cdot 0.2^2 \cdot 0.8^2\right] = 0.03072$$

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  As for your question, yes, you are correct.